# Reordering of dataframe rows/cols not working when set within a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to create a function that reorders the rows and columns of a data frame. However it doesn't work, yet if I try to reorder the dataframe manually everything is fine and so I must have a basic grasp of how to reorder.

Here is my function:

```
CorrOrder <- function (df, new_df) {

  new_order = c(19:24, 7:12, 1:6, 13:18)

  new_df <- df[new_order, new_order]
}

#This does absolutely nothing and doesn't return an error

CorrOrder(AllData[["DataUnsorted"]][["DataFrameZXWY"]],
           AllData[["DataFrameWXYZ"]])
```

This works just fine:

```
AllData[["DataFrameWXYZ"]] <- AllData[["DataUnsorted"]][["DataFrameZXWY"]][c(19:24, 7:12, 1:6, 13:18), c(19:24, 7:12, 1:6, 13:18)]
```

This will create some sample data:

```
data.frame(replicate(24,sample(0:1,24,rep=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things going wrong:

- `new_df` should not be an input value to your function but rather an output value.
- Your function does not have an output value.

Try this:

```
CorrOrder <- function(df) {
  new_order = c(19:24, 7:12, 1:6, 13:18)
  new_df <- df[new_order, new_order]
  return(new_df)
}

CorrOrder(AllData[["DataUnsorted"]][["DataFrameZXWY"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't returning anything. For example, this results in nothing as well:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3))
test_function <- function(df) {
  df_new <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(a = a + 2)
}
test_function(df)
```

Take out the new variable name and arrow and your code might work:

```
test_function <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(a = a + 2)
}
```

Or:

```
test_function <- function(df) {
  df_new <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(a = a + 2)
  return(df_new)
}
```